How can I draw missing vertical lines in tabular?
I want to draw missing vertical lines in a tabular. I think \multirow{2}{*}{} prevents table's vertical line to be drawn.
My code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{table*}[!t]  %
        \centering
        \caption{Results ...}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          \textbf{Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Workflow} & Method
          & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Completion                                                 \\ Time (min)}}
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Gas Used for                                               \\
          \textit{submitJob} (gas)}}
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Gas Used for                                               \\
          \textit{processPayment} (gas)}}
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Actual/Complete                                            \\ Cost
          (\textit{Cent})}}
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Failed}}                                                   \\
          \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
                        &       $|V|$                   & $|E|$                                                \\
          \hline
          $T_1$         & 16                            & 28 & ALGO & 27 & 1722983 & 1942770 & 0.827/0.827 & 0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{center}
\end{document}

output:

Wanted output:

Your code produced error as landscape not defined, please check and update

Don't use vertical lines if you use the booktabs package (and also don't use vertical lines if you don't use the booktabs package)

Should your title read: "How can I draw missing vertical lines in tabular?"?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz updated

@MadyYuvi Thanks fixed

If you set the option landscape for the geometry package, the entire document will be typeset in landscape mode -- no need for \begin{landscape} and \end{landscape}.

You can use nicematrix with the hvlines option. The command for both multirow and multicolumn cells is \Block.
Remember that \Block does not cause the cells to be skipped so && is necessary between the Workflow and Method cells. Also don't forget to compile twice.
The line \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt} is optional and creates some additional vertical space between rows.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{table*}[!t]  %
        \centering
        \caption{Results ...}
        \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccccc}[hvlines]
          \Block{2-1}{\textbf{Test}} & \Block{1-2}{Workflow} && \Block{2-1}{Method} & \Block{2-1}{Completion\\Time (min)}
                        & \Block{2-1}{Gas Used for\\ \textit{submitJob} (gas)}
                        & \Block{2-1}{Gas Used for\\ \textit{processPayment} (gas)}
                        & \Block{2-1}{Actual/Complete\\ Cost (\textit{Cent})}
                        & \Block{2-1}{Failed}\\
          & $|V|$ & $|E|$ \\
          $T_1$ & 16 & 28 & ALGO & 27 & 1722983 & 1942770 & 0.827/0.827 & 0
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{center}
\end{document}


If you're going to use the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package, don't use vertical lines. No way, no how.

Do note that if you specify option landscape while loading the geometry package, the entire document will be typeset in landscape mode. No need for \begin{landscape} and \end{landscape}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,calc}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} c @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\widthof{Workflow}-4\tabcolsep}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Results \dots}
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{wc{\mylen}} *{7}{c} @{}}
  \toprule
  Test
  & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{Workflow} 
  & Method
  & \mytab{Completion   \\ Time (min)}
  & \mytab{Gas used for \\ \textit{submitJob} (gas)}
  & \mytab{Gas used for \\ \textit{processPayment} (gas)}
  & \mytab{Actual/Complete \\ Cost (\textit{Cent})}
  & Failed \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
  & $V$ & $E$ \\
  \midrule
  $T_1$ & 16 & 28 & ALGO & 27 & 1722983 & 1942770 & 0.827/0.827 & 0 \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thanks. Your answer is actually my first choice and the correct way. But unfortunately my university forces us to use vertical-lines in tabular for our thesis :-(

@alper if you need vertical lines, you can't use booktabs. It's stated quite clearly in the manual... there are other packages, like nicematrix or tabularray, that probably fulfill better your objective.

If nothing else works, I'd choose a naive approach:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{table*}[!t]  %
            \centering
            \caption{Results ...}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
              \hline
              \textbf{Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Workflow} & Method
                            & Completion  
                            & Gas Used for 
                            & Gas Used for 
                            & Actual/Complete 
                            & Failed \\ 
                            & $|V|$ & $|E|$ 
                            &
                            & Time (min) 
                            & \textit{submitJob} (gas) 
                            & \textit{processPayment} (gas) 
                            & Cost (\textit{Cent}) 
                            & \\
              \hline
              $T_1$         & 16                            & 28 & ALGO & 27 & 1722983 & 1942770 & 0.827/0.827 & 0 \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table*}
    \end{center}
%\end{landscape}
\end{document}

Granted, the "Failed" isn't positioned in the middle any longer, but that's true for "Method" as well
